# Accord avec le verbe avoir : ça m'a beaucoup touchée ?

Tags: accord, participe-passé

Je me demande quelle phrase est juste, si je suis une fille :

> Merci pour votre cadeau, qui m'a beaucoup touch**ée**.

ou

> Merci pour votre cadeau, qui m'a beaucoup touch**é**.

J'ai des vagues souvenirs d'une règle concernant l'accord avec le COD placé avant... mais en voyant ces deux phrases, j'ai des doutes tout d'un coup !

Merci d'avance !

Comment: Pas de doute. Merci pour votre question, qui m'a mise de bonne humeur...

Answer (score 5):

La première est correcte : on fait l'accord avec avoir s'il y a un complément d'objet direct qui précède le verbe, comme ça.

> Quelle jupe as-tu choisi**e** ?
>
> Il me les a donné**s**.

Mais on ne fait pas l'accord si le COD suit le verbe.

> Tu as choisi quelle jupe ?
>
> Il m'a donné les livres.

Faites attention : on **ne fait pas l'accord** avec les compléments d'objet indirects.

> Nous leur avons téléphon**é**.

Comment: I see. I read the edit to the comment which made more sense. Perhaps im just tired :P merci @GAMPUB !

Comment: Your examples/explanations seem correct, but assuming that the OP’s main issue is whether or not there’s agreement when the preceding direct object is a personal [feminine] pronoun (like the example.. “m’a touché/e”) & not like your example where the DO is something else), would there be agreement, depending on the gender represented by the personal pronoun?  For example, would it be “Cette jupe m’a effrayée” (if the speaker is feminine & would the “**é**" be there to agree with the “m’”/her [& not w/“la jupe”])? (& in “Cette jupe m’a fait[e] craquer,” would there be agreement with “fait/e”?)

Comment: Yes i saw that after i wrote it. In time, ill edit to better address the issue.

Comment: Cool! I apologize if my comment merely (re-)addressed issues already mentioned in @GAMPUB 's comments, which (judging from the one-sided nature of your comments/conversation above) were deleted before I had a chance to read them.

Comment: @PapaPoule no thats quite alright! He was actually discussing something else.

Comment: Également on fait un accord même si l'objet direct précède le verbe d'une proposition relative : "Merci pour la cravate que j'ai portée hier."

Comment: @HarryAudus les exemples seront appréciés, peut-être un [edit] ?

Comment: Les exemples le montrent mais il faudrait préciser dans la réponse qu'on accorde le participe passé avec le COD (et non avec le sujet).

Answer (score 0):

Avec l'auxiliaire avoir, on accorde le participe passé avec le complément d'objet direct si celui-ci est placé avant le verbe.

Dans ton cas, cadeau est le sujet, toucher le verbe, et "moi" le complément d'objet direct.
Donc, en partant du postulat que la personne qui s'exprime est une femme, la formule correcte est :

> Merci pour ce cadeau qui m'a beaucoup touchée

A noter que cela va dans les 2 sens: hors contexte, employé le féminin ou le masculin permettra au moins de déterminer le sexe de la personne qui s'exprime...