# Four different forms of the past participle of “laisser”: Which one to use?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, participe-passé, infinitif

> Woman: Il ne m'a jamais laissée tomber.

In the sentence above, the speaker is a **woman**, and the “il” refers to a certain **man** and the “me” refers to a **woman** (the speaker).

I’ve just learnt that there are four different forms of the past participle of the verb “laisser”: “laissé”, “laissés”, “laissée”, and “laissées”.

I’d like to know why “laissée” (not the other three) is used in this sentece. Which of the four to use depends on what, I wonder?

And I have another question: Are these four words pronounced any differently from one another?

Comment: Same pronunciation. For the rest, it's about conjugaison. "Être" as an auxiliary (accord with subject), or with "avoir", depends on where is the COD (accord with the COD).

Comment: Regardez par exemple [cette question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/16997/8349)

Comment: Plural, Feminine, Masculine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [*avoir* verbs](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs/) like *laisser*, there's agreement only when the [direct object](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/direct-objects/) precedes the verb.

In your example, *m'* (short for *me*) refers to a woman, so the past participle is feminine singular: *laissée*.

When there's no direct object, or the direct object is masculine, you use the base form *laissé*. You need *laissés* and *laissées* when the preceding direct object is plural masculine or feminine, respectively.

Answer (score 5):

**Il s'agit d'un cas particulier: il est plutôt préconisé de laisser *laissé* invariable, quoique l'autre forme (*laissée*) puisse être utilisée.**

Selon le Grevisse 2011 :

> Le Conseil supérieur de la langue française estimant que *« laissé »*
>   forme avec l'infinitif qui suit une périphrase analogue à *« fait »* +
>   infinitif, recommande l'invariabilité de ce participe, ce que l'Ac.
>   2000 entérine de manière explicite.

**On devrait donc plutôt dire:**

> Il m'a laissé tomber.

comme

> Il m'a fait tomber.

Voici une explication: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/laisser/1

voir la partie verbe, bas de page:

> Les exemples ci-dessus respectent la règle habituelle d'accord du
>   participe passé suivi d'un infinitif. Cependant, l'application de
>   cette règle étant parfois malaisée, particulièrement dans les formes
>   pronominales, et l'accord restant incertain dans l'usage, on pourra,
>   comme pour le verbe faire, généraliser l'invariabilité du participe
>   passé de laisser dans le cas où il est suivi d'un infinitif. Il est
>   donc possible d'écrire :
>    - Elle s'est laissé mourir comme Elle s'est fait maigrir ;
>    - Je les ai laissé partir comme Je les ai fait partir.

ou:

http://www.langue-fr.net/Laisser-accord-du-participe-passe-laisse

ou encore

http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/l-accord-du-participe-passe-laisse-devant-un-infinitif-182.php

**Dans le cas plus général, on accorde le verbe avec le COD si celui-ci est placé avant:**

> Il m'a vue.