# grammaire en français

Tags: grammaire

When one states a sentence such as:

"They have accepted this job"

I would usually write this in my language journal as:

"Ils ont accepté cet emploi"

However, I was wondering if because of our 3rd person pronoun being plural, if we would have to change the past participle (accepté) to also be in the plural, such as this sentence:

"Ils ont acceptés cet emploi."

(I am not certain if the above is correct, but this is the question that I may pose).

Merci en avance !

Comment: Voir aussi [Accord avec le verbe avoir : ça m'a beaucoup touchée ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16997/accord-avec-le-verbe-avoir-ça-ma-beaucoup-touchée?noredirect=1&lq=1])

Answer (score 1):

Je n'ai pas trouvé de duplicate mais cette question a forcément déjà été posée.

Il y a une règle en français, on n'accorde pas le participe passé **avec l'auxiliaire avoir** quand le COD (le complément, ici "*cet emploi*") est placé **après** le verbe.

Voici [la règle en question](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/l-accord-du-participe-passe-employe-avec-l-auxiliaire-avoir-179.php).

Comment: et quand il est placé avant, c'est **avec le COD** qu'il s'accorde.